# How are Bazel's cc_library include paths expanded?

Tags: bazel

I'm using Bazel 0.15.2 to build a third-party dependency (say, "tp_dep") that uses "make" for my project. This means I've had to write my own BUILD file for that dependency.

They have many `Makefile`s that localize include paths to the various subdirectories, so my targets end up with several custom `copts` flags to add those paths to the search space. The problem I'm seeing is that `"-Iexternal/tp_dep/path/to/directory"` in my copts field doesn't end up being useful for `#include "file_from_path_to_directory.h"`.

Note: I have `"path/to/directory/file_from_path_to_directory.h"` in my target's `hdrs` list.

When I inspect the `--verbose_failures`, I see that dependencies from other cc_library targets are included as `"bazel-out/host/genfiles/external/tp_dep/some/path"`.

I thus changed my copts line to `"-iquote$(GENDIR)/external/tp_dep/path/to/directory"` and still I see trouble. I've also tried `$(BINDIR)` instead of `$(GENDIR)`.

What is the correct way to add these kinds of include directives?

Comment: copts = ["-I$(GENDIR)/myprojectdir"] works for me ('I' being upper case i)